# Is use of std::forward with auto&& the right thing to do

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to understand whether using `std::forward` with `auto&&` variables is the right way to pass those variables to allow move.

Assume there is a function:

```
void moveWidget(Widget&& w);
```

And the caller - two variables to refer to rvalue and lvalue:

```
Widget w;
auto&& uniRefLV = w;            // lvalue initialiser, 
                                // uniRefLV's type is Widget&

auto&& uniRefRV = std::move(w); // rvalue initialiser, 
                                // uniRefRV's type is Widget&&
```

We know that a variable of type `auto&&` is a *universal reference* because there is a type deduction taking place. Which means both `uniRefRV` and `uniRefLV` are *universal references*.

In my example it is obvious that `uniRefRV` is *rvalue* and `uniRefLV` is *lvalue* but conceptually they are both *universal references* and if definition was different they could represent either *rvalue* or *lvalue*.

Now, I want to call `moveWidget()` and perfect forward those universal references types. The guideline (by Scott Meyers) says:

> Pass and return *rvalue references* via `std::move`, *universal references* via `std::forward`.

And unless I am completely misinterpreting the guideline it seems logical to use `std::forward`. But let's consider all possible choices:

```
// (1) std::move:
moveWidget(std::move(uniRefLV)); // Compiles and looks fine
                                 // but violates the guideline?
                                 // (unconditionally casts lvalue to rvalue)

moveWidget(std::move(uniRefRV)); // Same as above - but not an issue here
                                 // as we cast rvalue to rvalue

// (2) std::forward with Widget:
moveWidget(std::forward<Widget>(uniRefLV)); // Compiles, follows the guideline
                                            // but doesn't look right - what if
                                            // we didn't know Widget's type?

moveWidget(std::forward<Widget>(uniRefRV)); // Same as above

// (3) std::forward with decltype:
moveWidget(std::forward<decltype(uniRefLV)>(uniRefLV)); // Fails to compile! (VC10)
                                                        // follows the guideline
                                                        // has nice and short syntax :)

moveWidget(std::forward<decltype(uniRefRV)>(uniRefRV)); // Compiles fine
```

Do you think we should treat both references `uniRefLV` and `uniRefRV` equally and which of three options should we use for perfect forwarding?

Comment: Actually `std::forward<int>(uniRef)` is equivalent to `std::move(uniRef)`.

Comment: Use `std::forward<decltype(uniRef)>(uniRef)`. This avoids explicitely saying `int`.

Comment: @MWid `std::move` also avoids that. And it also avoids saying `uniRef` twice.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Of course, but if we don't know, if `uniRef` is a rvalue or lvalue reference and we only want to steal from rvalue references, then using `std::forward<decltype(uniRef)>(uniRef)` is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting decltype(uniRef) - I added this into revised version of my question as it helps to better explain what choices we have.

Comment: Your edit didn't change much. "We know that uniRefRV and uniRefLV are both universal references and can either be bound to lvalue (the former) or rvalue (the latter)." *NO they can not be bound to **either***. One **is** an lvalue reference, and the other **is** an rvalue reference. There is no "can" here. They *are*. No possibilities. And your function *still leaves you no choice but to pass an rvalue*. There is no perfect forwarding to do here, because there are no templates around. Forget about universal references unless you are dealing with generic code.

Comment: `template <typename T> void f(T&& t) {
    /* Here t can indeed be an lvalue or an rvalue reference.
       This is where one would want to do perfect forwarding */
}`

Comment: I think my understanding improves with each your comment (although you might feel opposite :) - thanks. I appreciate both variables represent rvalue/lvalue. What I was trying to ask is if there is a variable of type `auto&&` it is a universal reference and can (in general) either represent lvalue or rvalue and whether we need to `forward` or `move` it to allow move to happen. I am going to accept your answer but can you please be specific and say option (1) is the right thing to do (if you agree) for other people's benefits. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the guideline. Or at least taking it too literally.

I think there are three important things to realise here.

First, all types are known here. The advice for universal references applies mostly for generic code with templates where you don't know at all if something is or takes an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

Second, the function takes an rvalue reference: you have to pass an rvalue. Period. There is no choice here.

And the logical conclusion is that you *do not* want to pass an universal reference: whatever you pass has to be an rvalue, it can never be an lvalue. Universal references can be lvalues (if they are instantiated as lvalue references). Passing an universal reference along means "I don't know what kind of reference this is, and I can pass it either as rvalue or lvalue, so I am passing it along exactly as I got it". The case in this question is more like "I know exactly what I must pass, so that's what I'll be passing".

Comment: Agree it is too obvious in my example what type auto&& refers to. I am trying to understand the general rule - and exceptions if there are any. Let me rephrase the question slightly to emphasise that uniRef may actually be lvalue or rvalue. I'll also change int to Widget as moving integral types doesn't make any sense anyway.

Comment: Ok, but I think that if you rephrase it you will see the guideline making perfect sense again (however, keep my second point in mind: you cannot apply the guideline if your hands are tied).

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume that the case isn't as simplistic as it seems. Instead of `giveMeInt` we have something like this:

```
template <typename T>
typename complex_computation<T>::type giveMeSomething(T t);
```

And instead of `moveMe`, you have something that actually takes a universal reference and therefore doesn't require an unconditional `std::move`.

```
template <typename T>
void wantForwarded(T&&);
```

**Now** you actually need perfect forwarding.

```
auto&& uniRef = giveMeSomething(iDontKnowTheTypeOfThis);
wantForwarded(std::forward<decltype(uniRef)>(uniRef);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you got a bit mixed up here. Neither `uniRefLV` nor `uniRefRV` are "universal references". They're just variables, and both have a definite type. Both types happen to be reference types, but that's immaterial.

To call `moveWidget`, you have to use `std::move` in both cases, and in both cases the semantics are that after the move, your original `w` has been moved from and is thus no longer in a definite state. (The best you can do with it is either destroy it or reassign to it.)

Now, by contrast, a true *universal reference* is a *template argument*, and it must always be of the canonical form:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&);
//                            ^^^^^^

foo(bar());
foo(x);
foo(std::move(y));
```

That is,

- the template is a *function* template,
- the template parameter `T` occurs as the function parameter `T &&`, and
- the template argument of the actualized specialization is *deduced*.

When those conditions are met, `T &&` is the universal reference, and you pass it on via `std::forward<T>`, which preserves the correct reference type.

Answer (score 0):

**(1).a** 
 It does not violate guideline. You specifically say *"i don't need that lvalue any more so take it"* that's basically what std::move is for. And if you continue to use uniRefLV after you've done std::move on it - this is against guideline. The value is gone (potentially), you passed it over. That's what *Scott* says.

**(1).b** 
 That's legit. Though std::move is unneeded there, but it does simplify reading source code.

**(2), (3)** 
 We don't have to provide template argument for std::forward. It shall be deduced by a compiler! At least that's what my understanding is. And I don't see a point of doing it manually. Forward just remove's references (&& and &) from the type definition. That is why it is called *forwarding* and used for data forwarding. When you have function:
    template 
    void foo(T && t);

It may be instantiated to either of:

```
void foo(SomeType & t);
void foo(SomeType && t);
void foo(const SomeType & t);
void foo(const SomeType && t);
void foo(volatile SomeType & t);
void foo(volatile SomeType && t);
void foo(const volatile SomeType & t);
void foo(const volatile SomeType && t);
```

For example:

```
Widget a;
foo(a);
```

Will instantiate:

```
void foo(Widget & a);
```

Not:

```
void foo(Widget a);
```

So all those references are removed by a std::forward. And just `*modificator* SomeType t` is presented to whatever function inside of `foo()` it is passed to.